# Doctrine - how to initialize DB values

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, database-migration, symfony5

I use Doctrine 2.7.0 in a Symfony 5.0 Application.
I define my DB tables within my Entities with ORM Annotations.
I create a migration with Symfony maker like this

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

then I create the raw DB (mySql) from that with

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

This results in a nice fresh DB.

Now - I am wondering if it is possible to define base data for the tables with Annotations.
I don't mean to set default values for properties but to add entries to tables which the DB allways needs.

So basically I want the migration to insert entries to the DB too.
Is that possible?

Comment: i dont think so, you can define default values and other db things, but some base data not. You can use fixtures to insert dummy data https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: Yeah - but isn't fixtures ment to be used for testing? Like you said it's dummy data. Dunno if this can (or should) be used for base data creation as well...

Comment: this bundle shouldn't be included in prod environment, but data why not. you can define proper data not dummy data

Comment: Any idea on how to tell the FixturesBundle to use my DEV-DB-settings instead the TEST settings? I have ".env" and ".env.test" - Fixtures uses the latter but should use the ".env" settings...

Comment: when you are registering Bundle you should define environment https://prnt.sc/qqqbfa

Comment: I have it defined like in your link for "dev" and "test" - but I don't see how I can differentiate in the load-functions in my Fixture-Class(es) to choose either "dev" or "test". It's allways applying it to the test-definitions.

Comment: read also answer from `pat`. https://prnt.sc/qqqbfa this means that fixtures can be used in DEV and TEST, if you are running development you can load fixtures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data that is required for the application to run like lookup tables should actually be part of the migration. You should also provide the proper rollback procedure for that data in order to keep your migration backwards compatible.

You should however refrain from using Doctrine for those migrations, since a later change to the Entity mapping etc. would break all previous migrations.

You could technically use fixtures to load this data. Though by default fixtures truncate the entire database unless the [--append](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures) flag is specified leaving it rather unsuited for this kind of operation as removing data sets with this option is not possible.

Comment: Can you recommend any workflow / tools / tool-chain that would suit for Symfony-Doctrine Annotation Declarations and following migration including the data (like lookup tables)?

Comment: Since migrations require to stay independent of your code, I'm afraid there isn't too much byway of libraries that can assist you with generating the data sets. Migrations are intended to be rather static to secure compatibility. 
You can however use a DBMS like for example MySQL Workbench in case of MySQL to at least generate the statements for you.

Comment: Well - thanks. I configured the fixtures bundle to do the job. I am aware of that fixtures allways renew the whole DB. That's OK in my scenario. So I accept your answere.